# Python - remove certain values from a dictionary and then return it

Tags: python

I am trying to remove certain values from a dict and return it.
For example, if the dict contains a value that is a string with a length less than 6 it would be removed from the dict. How can I iterate through the dict and return it in its edited state?

Comment: Entire key-value should be removed if length of value is less than 6 ??

Comment: For tasks like this, you don’t remove items, you create a new dict overriding the original.

Comment: Hi guys, what I mean is how do I remove just the value and not the key. Say the key has multiple values but I just want to delete one of them?

Comment: @verdy Your description above does not make that clear. I suggest you expand on the description and provide a code example with an example of the input and expected output also any attempts you have made. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page may be of assistance.

Comment: def remove_short_words(words_dict):
   
    new_dict = {}
    
    for key,value in words_dict.items():
        if len(value) > 6:
            new_dict[key] = value
       
            
    return new_dict                      (This doesn't seem to work at all)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're just removing values that have a length less than 6, all you need is this:

```
d = {'a': 'asdfasdf', 'b': 'asdf'}

while True:
    flag = True
    for i in d:
        if len(d[i]) < 6:
            del d[i]
            flag = False
            break
    if flag:
        break

print d

{'a': 'asdfasdf'}
```

Comment: This could be a lot simpler.
`>>> {k : v for k,v in d.items() if len(v) < 6}` == 
`{'b': 'asdf'}`

Answer (score 0):

when working with dict it is good to use `items()`:

lets consider `d = {1: "myname",  2:"mynamex", 3:"mynamey",4:"name"}`

```
for key, value in d.items():
    if len(value) < 6:
        del d[key]
print(d)
```

Ans: strings less than 6 chars are deleted

```
{1: 'myname', 2: 'mynamex', 3: 'mynamey'}
```

Note:

Python 2:

```
for key, value in d.iteritems():
```

Python 3:

```
for key, value in d.items()
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do it using single loop,

```
def doAct(s):
   for key in s.keys():
      if len(s[key]) < 6:
         del s[key]
   return s
```

if you use `for key in s`, you will get error `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`.

Answer (score 0):

This can end done in a single line with so called *dict comprehension*:

```
{k:v for k,v in d.items() if len(v)<6}
```

Internally it will unwrapped into a cycle but it's easier and less space to make a typo. 
You may use diffefent conditions in loop or even make for in for.